# How to get possibility to import Access files using SSMS version 18

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms

I have installed SSMS and in the import wizard is missing the option

[image]

to for data import of Access files. This picture is from older SSMS version. Could you please advise which enhancement to SSMS should be installed and where is it possible to download it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Access Database Engine.

From the [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-access-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017#officeDownloads) regarding imports of Access files to SQL Server via SSMS wizard:

> ### Get the files you need to connect to Access
>
> You may have to download the connectivity components for Microsoft
>   Office data sources, including Access and Excel, if they're not
>   already installed. Download the latest version of the connectivity
>   components for both Access and Excel files here: [Microsoft Access
>   Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=54920).
>
> The latest version of the components can open files created by earlier
>   versions of Access.
>
> If the computer has a 32-bit version of Office, then you have to
>   install the 32-bit version of the components, and you also have to
>   ensure that you run the package in 32-bit mode.

If you have problems with the 32/64 bit versions, make sure to [execute the correct import/export wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017). You need to have installed the correct Access engine before though.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link and advice. Unfortunately I was not able to install the component as 32-bit version gives an error that my Office is 64-bit and when I download 64-bit component, then I get message that my Office is 32-bit version. How can I run the package in the 32-bit mode please? My Office 365 is 32-bit version. Thank you for further advice.

Comment: I've added a comment for the import wizard. You have to install the Access engine that matches your office bit mode, then run the same wizard mode (your SSMS might be 64 bits but you can run the wizard in 32 bits).

Comment: Hi, the problem is that neither 32bit nor 64bit component version is possible to install. The link is useful when the component is already installed.